# The meaning of "The paradox of courage is that a man must be a little careless of his life even in order to keep it." — G. K. Chesterton

Tags: meaning, quotes

I recently came across this quote by G. K. Chesterton.

> The paradox of courage is that a man must be a little careless of his life even in order to keep it.

(Note that the version I initially saw stated, "The paradox of courage is that one must be a little careless of life to keep it.”)

Originally, I had difficulty interpreting this quote as the phrasing is a little archaic. After a brief period of contemplation, I interpreted it as "one must be a little careless of one's life to keep courage."

Later, I found an [excerpt](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/144476-take-the-case-of-courage-no-quality-has-ever-so) from his book Orthodoxy which addresses a similar idea. With this context, my new interpretation is that "having courage means being able to risk their life in order to survive." I think "even" in the quote emphasises that this is the minimal effort they have to make in order to live.

---

Firstly, I would like to know if my interpretation is correct or read others' interpretations.

Secondly, I would like to understand how I would interpret similar sentences in the future. I primarily had difficulty understanding what "it" referred to and how "courage" had anything to do with what followed. I was also confused by the inclusion of "even" in the sentence. I was reading it in two possible ways: "his life even, in order to keep it" and "his life, even in order to keep it." I am not an expert in grammar so I do not know if this makes sense, but I could not understand if "even" was associated with the expression before or the expression after.

Comment: This is a run-of-the-mill case of ambiguity as to what the antecedent of a pronoun is. Posting a formal answer about its intended meaning would illuminate this particular text but not provide any new insight into English language and usage.

Comment: @jsw29 That was certainly part of the question, but I think the second part of my question asked a bit more. I think an answer to this part would not be dependent on this particular text. Also, if I were to require the meaning of a particular text, is this not the right place?

Comment: I don't know what "even" means in either of the following phrases: "even in order to keep his life" or "even in order to keep his courage"  I don't know what it means to be "a *little* careless of [one's] life".

Comment: Although I dispute the notion that there is any ambiguity about the antecedent of *it* here (it’s clearly the noun phrase *his life*), I find @jsw29’s analysis of the potential benefit of posting an answer fascinating and useful. Still, though answers that can be applied broadly must be more valuable, I don’t see that answering *sui generis* questions should be discouraged. I suppose this point belongs on [the meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum, see [Are questions about explaining what the text mean on-topic?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14978), [Should this question about the meaning of "a friend to all is a friend to none" be reopened?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15005).

Comment: I just can't answer this given the name.

Comment: You need the context. A vigorous Googling shows that this quote is widely shared and seldom properly cited. Chesterton had a habit of setting up an argument with several paragraphs and then summing it up with a single, pithy, quotable sentence, but these don't always survive outside their host bodies. This comes from [a short piece called "The Methuselahite](https://www.online-literature.com/chesterton/all-things-considered/23/)," collected in the volume _All Things Considered_. Chesterton doesn't fully flesh out his implication here, but it would be that those who prioritize longevity over

Comment: over other worthwhile priorities like courage and duty, might in fact shorten or simply cheapen their life. His construction about "keeping one's life" is almost certainly a conscious echo of the biblical passage Matthew 16:25; Chesterton loved these kinds of constructions of apparent paradox: "Whoever wants to X must -X, and whoever -Xs will X."

Comment: @AndyBonner Thank you for the context. After reading the short piece, the quote makes much more sense now. I did come across the term "Mathuselahite" in my research, but I presumed the quote was from a book and I wanted a quicker answer than reading an entire book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passage asserts Chesterton’s perceived incongruity, that keeping one’s life sometimes requires risking it. The *even* highlights that the reasons for carelessness extend so far as to include protecting one’s life, the very object that the carelessness puts at risk. Thus the *even* emphasizes the paradoxical nature of the situation.

Comment: Is "even" a synonym there for "merely" or "just"?

Comment: Are you parsing it as "in order *even* to keep it"?  Or "even must risk his life"?  It feels to me like *even* is in the wrong place.

Comment: Or is it the Snagglepuss "even", "his life, even". https://www.google.com/search?q=snagglepuss+even+youtube&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&oq=snagglepuss+even+youtube&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCTk5NzVqMGoxNagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:d600f213,vid:VoV6-bY75vw,st:0

Comment: @TimR, from among your choices, “in order **even** to keep it.”

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Together with your explanation and discussion in the comments about *even*, I have a better understanding of what it means in this text. I have not accepted the answer yet because I would have also liked to see an answer to the second question about how I could interpret similar sentences in the future.

Comment: Which sentences would (or would not) count as similar?

Comment: I had difficulty understanding this without context, so I guess I want general advice on how one would decipher sentences lacking a similar degree of context. Did you give this answer purely based on the quote or did you do some background research? If you think it is simply impossible to understand without context, that is fine. Then, how could you try to gain as much as possible without the context?

Comment: I interpreted it in isolation. That’s very often impossible to do, so perhaps here it amounted to going out on a limb. As for advice for enhancing one’s abilities at deciphering, the best I can come up with is read lots more comparable writing, and perhaps writing from earlier periods. Read poets? Read Jane Austen? If you really want to tempt fate in the incomprehensibility department, read philosophers.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum, philosophical writings are often difficult to understand, but philosophers normally **strive** to be as clear and precise as their subject matter allows, unlike poets, novelists, etc., who often **deliberately** create ambiguities and puzzles for their readers (and are praised for doing so).